# finding min and max in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters 'done'. Once 'done' is entered, print out the
> largest and smallest of the numbers. If the user enters anything other
> than a valid number catch it with a try/except and put out an
> appropriate message and ignore it.

This is the question I have tried many ways but unable to achieve min and max numbers. Please help me with the code:

```
largest = None
samllest = None
while True:
    num = input("Enter Numbers:")
    if num == 'done' :
        break
    else:
        try:
            n = int(num)
        except:
            print("Invalid Input")
```

Comment: You seem to do a good job of taking and handling the input. Here's an idea: put all those numbers in a list, and when the user inputs `done`, use the built-ins [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) and [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) to return the relevant numbers

Comment: yep I taught of using the list but for that user need to mention the list size initially but I dont want that. Is there any other way.

Comment: Why would they need to do that? This is not C... Aren't you familiar with the [`list.append()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) method - *appends x to the __end__ of the sequence*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do a list of inputed numbers:

```
numbers=[]
while True:
    num = input("Enter Numbers:")
    if num == 'done' :
        break
    else:
        try:
            numbers.append(int(num))
        except:
            print("Invalid Input")
print("Min", str(min(numbers)))
print("Max", str(max(numbers)))
```

you will have this result:

```
Enter Numbers:2
Enter Numbers:3
Enter Numbers:4
Enter Numbers:5
Enter Numbers:6
Enter Numbers:7
Enter Numbers:8
Enter Numbers:done
Min 2
Max 8
```

Comment: No need to cast the `print` arguments to `str` - it is done automatically

Comment: yes your right. i have this mania to cast all elements.

Answer (score 1):

Using the walrus operator for fun & brevity:

```
numbers = list()
while (the_input := input('Enter a number:')) != 'done':
    numbers.append(int(the_input))
print(f'{min(numbers)=}, {max(numbers)=}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you re, probe it:

```
lg = None
sm = None
s = None

while s != 'done':
    s = input("Enter numbers:")
    if s.isdigit():
        s = int(s)
        if lg == None and sm == None:
            lg = s
            sm = s
            
        if lg <= s:
            lg = s
        if sm >= s:
            sm = s
            
print(f"Min: {sm}, Max: {lg}")
```

And you can test it:

```
Enter numbers:5
Enter numbers:6
Enter numbers:1
Enter numbers:5
Enter numbers:8
Enter numbers:9
Enter numbers:done
Min: 1, Max: 9
```

And if you want a try/except block...

```
lg = None
sm = None
s = None

while s != 'done':
    try:
        s = int(input("Enter numbers:"))
        if lg == None and sm == None:
            lg = s
            sm = s
            
        if lg <= s:
            lg = s
        if sm >= s:
            sm = s
            
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        
print(f"Min: {sm}, Max: {lg}")
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help you ;). Please consider to mark it as correct answer.